# Удлинение имен файлов на shell

Tags: shell

Как написать на shell программу, которая выполняет удлинение имен файлов до указанной длины заданным знаком?

Answer (score 1):

Прочитать имя файла, посчитать количество символов, вычесть его из заданного знаком, добавить к имени рандом недостающих,переименовать. В общих чертах как то так. Иначе недостаточно данных.

Comment: Как можно посчитать количество символов в имени?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash) вот к примеру на bash считают количество символов в переменной, а тут (https://overcoder.net/q/6042/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-bash) как раз имя считывают.